# ios webview not showing up after setting delegate

Tags: ios, uiwebview, delegates

I'm setting up a webview programmatically, and everything works until I actually set the delegate.

### MainPageViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainPageViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webViewForStories;

@end
```

### MainPageViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 300)];    
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://myurl.com/mypage";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    webViewForStories = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, webView.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    NSString *urlAddressForStories = @"http://myurl.com/mysecondpage";
    NSURL *urlForStories = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddressForStories];
    NSURLRequest *requestObjForStories = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlForStories];
    [webViewForStories loadRequest:requestObjForStories];
    [self.view addSubview:webViewForStories];
    [webViewForStories setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"webviewForStories delegate is %@", webViewForStories.delegate);
    NSLog(@"webviewForStories is %@", webViewForStories);
}
```

Here's what the page looks like when I set the delegate:

[image: Page when I set the delegate]

Here's what the page looks like when I DON'T set the delegate:

[image: Page when I do not set the delegate]
The only difference is this line of code:

```
[webViewForStories setDelegate:self];
```

Here is the relevant output from NSLog:

```
2012-12-26 14:18:40.720 WGGB for iPad[3144:907] webviewForStories delegate is <MainPageViewController: 0x1f878cc0>
2012-12-26 14:18:40.721 WGGB for iPad[3144:907] webviewForStories is <UIWebView: 0x1f8838c0; frame = (0 300; 768 1004); layer = <CALayer: 0x1f883920>>
```

This is a mystery, any help is appreciated. FYI, I tried commenting out the first webview, I thought they might be conflicting, but it didn't make a difference.

EDIT:

Here are my delegate methods:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webview finished loading");
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webview started loading");
}

// This function allows me to intercept links clicked in a webview and open in
// a navigation window with a back button.
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

    NSLog(@"urlstring is %@", urlString);

    // Only catching links without "mobile" in the url (i.e. stories)
    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"/mobile"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location == NSNotFound &&[urlString rangeOfString:@"twitter"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"fb://"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"liverail"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"about:blank"].location == NSNotFound) {
        //DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

None of them seem to be getting called.

Comment: what are you doing in your web delegate methods? is the missing tableview the issue? what do you mean by works or the only difference?

Comment: Have you maybe implemented `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` by accident returning `NO`?

You could implement `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` and see if it gives you any pointers.

Comment: I updated the question to show the delegate methods, although none of them are getting called...

Comment: @calcinBhai, what makes you say I have a missing tableview?

Comment: the list of stories in your "works" screen shot, is it a html view displayed within the webview? or is it a UITableView?

Comment: It's html displayed in the webview.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... the problem was with this method:

```
// This function allows me to intercept links clicked in a webview and open in
// a navigation window with a back button.
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

    NSLog(@"urlstring is %@", urlString);

    // Only catching links without "mobile" in the url (i.e. stories)
    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"/mobile"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString     rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location == NSNotFound &&[urlString rangeOfString:@"twitter"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"fb://"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"liverail"].location == NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"about:blank"].location == NSNotFound) {
        //DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

The if statement was being caught on the initial loading of the webview so it was returning NO, which basically gave me a blank screen. I had to check if this was the initial load or not before allowing that if statement to run.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the delegate to the property instead of the ivar.

```
[self.webViewForStories setDelegate:self]
```

to get the webviews to call the delegate methods you have implemented.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives the same result. FYI I don't have an ivar, only the property.

Comment: is it possible to move your viewDidLoad code to ViewDidAppear? I am still not sure where you are going wrong.